# Does accord.net has lasso and ridge regression

Tags: accord.net

Recently I discovered for myself Lasso and Ridge regression in scikit python library. But as .Net developer I need the same functionality in accord.net Machine learning framework. I try to understand are they available in Accord.net. For example I see at accord net web site L1 and L2 regressor, and I know that [Lasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) and [Ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) are implemented with L1 regularization and L2 regularization. But still I'm not sure. Can anybody confirm/refute that L1 and L2 of accord net are the same as Lasso and Ridge regularization in scikit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far answer is the following. Lasso (L1) and Ridge (L2) in python has linear regression implemented. But Accord.net for L1 and L2 has only implemented for Logistic regression. This is clearly visible on screenshot from their web site:

[image: L1 and L2 has only logistic implementations]

Because Logisitc and Linear regression has different applications ( like apples and oranges ) I come to a conclusion that Ridge and Lasso Linear regression is not implemented in Accord.net.